# Replacing tr & td with div inside javascript file

Tags: jquery-ui

```
    var URI = OMSiteUrl + GetLevelZeroDisplay;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: URI, //URI
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        success: function (Json) {
            var r = new Array(), i = -1;
            var tr = '';
            tr = tr + '<tr>';
            if (Json != null) {

                var i;
                var len = Json.length;

                for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    if (Json[i].Publish == true || isadmin == True) {
                        if (isadmin == True) {
                            debugger;
                            tr = tr + '<td>'
                            tr = tr + '<table><tr><td>'
                            tr = tr + '<div id="theDiv" class="DivClass" style="text-align:center;">';
                            tr = tr + ' <div style="margin-right:16%;float:right;"> <img  id="btnAddNewLevelOne" src="../Images/add-icon.png" alt="ADD" onclick="BindSequencingLevelOne(' + Json[i].ID + ')" style="height: 12px; margin-right: 4px; margin-top: -5px;"></div>';
                            tr = tr + '<img  id="btnEdit" onclick="EditLevelZeroValue(' + Json[i].ID + ')" src="../Images/Edit-icon.png" title="Edit" alt="Smiley face" style="float:left;margin-left:11%;">';
                            tr = tr + " <label id='LevelLbl' class='wrap' style='height:20px;margin:19px 0 0 0px;z-index:2;top: 20px; color:white;max-width:68%;min-height:41px;white-space:initial;word-wrap: break-word;text-align:center;display: inline-block;vertical-align:middle; font-weight: 400; font-size: 14px; font-family: Segoe UI, Segoe, Tahoma, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;'> " + Json[i].Title + " </label>";
                            tr = tr + '<div><img  id="btnDelete" onclick="DeleteLevels(' + Json[i].ID + ')" src="../Images/delete-White.png" title="Delete"   alt="Smiley face" style="margin:-3px 0 0 19px;float: left;"></div>';
                            tr = tr + " </div> ";
                            tr = tr + " </td> ";
                            tr = tr + "</tr>";
                        }
```

Hi this is the code which will perform ajax call for getting levels . i want where ever i have use tr & td or table it should be replaced by div .In this code we are using tr & td so that data should come in each row ..this code is working fine but now i want to replace it with div.

plz help me out with this

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you want to replace rows with divs? Did you tried to code this itself? Is there a problem you can not resolve? Or you want somebody else to finish your job?

Comment: rows & columns are not good to use . i want to convert in to div only . i want only one example then i will do it my self . i tried but UI is totally breaking .